# What the reason of an error when I try to import matplotlib for python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I've got installed matplotlib module with conda but Im getting VSCode error when I try to run debugger. It seems that vscode doesn't see those module. maybe some problem with directories ?
Any suggestions ?

[image: t]

Comment: Did you install matplotlib? Using $ pip install matplotlib

Comment: just using Conda

Comment: [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my VScode used another environment.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments